# Why LDAPS (using DirectoryEntry with AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketLayer) requires credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

When trying to access to an active directory folder which isn't RootDSE, is there any different between LDAP and LDAPS (using `AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketLayer`) ?

When I'm trying to access to an active directory folder other than RootDSE without using `AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketLayer`, I'm able to do it but when I'm trying to access to an Active Directory folder other than RootDSE using `AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketLayer`, I get "Operation failed error" which happens due to binding error (missing username and password to access the AD).

Is it possible to use LDAPS without providing username and password (same as using LDAP)?

Comment: Whether you use LDAPS or LDAP protocol has nothing to do with Active Directory's requirements to authenticate. LDAPS only ensures data transfer confidentiality via transport layer encryption - it does **not** convey any kind of authentication information. I think there's something more at play that causes this behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

`AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketLayer` enforces a client certificate authentication to Active Directory, which is probably not what you want.

Use instead `AuthenticationTypes.Secure` and leave username/password empty to bind to Active Directory as your current user.

Comment: Thank you sk_ but I do need to use AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketLayer to keep to ldap packets secured.

Comment: Right, sorry. You could add the following Authentication flags: Signing and Sealing.

Comment: I tried.. But it still requires username and password.

Comment: Is your active directory configured to allow anonymous bind on the ldaps port ?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I configure it to allow anonymous bind ? And how can I check if it is already configured to allow anonymous bind?